# SpecFlow+ Runner cannot discover tests error

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I recently decided to get the SpecFlow+ 30 days trial and installed the NuGet package SpecFlow+ Runner which also installed the SpecFlow one. I registered the license key following their guides and started adding a feature file and a feature steps and got this error when building my solution:

```
An exception occurred while test discoverer 'SpecRunTestDiscoverer' was loading tests. Exception: Invalid configuration file (..path..)Specs\bin\Debug\Default.srprofile:There is an error in XML document (3, 28). -> Expected hex 0x in '{0}'.
```

Here is a snippet of the Default.srprofile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Settings projectName="" projectId="{}" />
  <Execution stopAfterFailures="3" testThreadCount="1" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
```

Can you please help me?

Note that the solution was built from scratch only to test SpecFlow+ features.
Also note that the scenario created is very basic and it works if used with other test engines(SpecFlow with MSUnit, xUnit or NUnit).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a bug in the NuGet client in the latest Visual Studio 2017 version.

Please have a look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/935

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know where i can find the Guid of my project? It sais in the workaround that i can use any valid Guid, but i don't know what that is.

Comment: If you open your csproj file with an text editor, you see a big XML file. Somewhere in it there is a element ProjectGuid. Use this